# How to set first value in "useState" function to true or false with "useEffect" function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, use-effect, use-state

I am running into a problem with my current code. The code below is supposed to grab a JSON response from my backend and set "data" in the useState function to true or false based on the backend's response. The issue I am having is that when I click on my button to redirect me to the page it must first go through this protected route in my react router. So it will run this script but the value of 'data' never changes. However, my console.log will output the correct boolean based on the JSON response sent from the backend. I am confused on how I can actually grab my JSON response on page load and set it to 'data' with useEffect? From my understanding, useEffect will only update my useState 'data' when the DOM re-renders.

In short, I want data to = true on page render by checking the JSON response from my backend using axios and if it is true I want to be redirected to the outlet.

I appreciate any help thanks.

```
 const useAuth = () => {
    
      const [data, setData] = useState(false);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAuthData = async () => {
          await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/auth')
            .then(resp => {
              console.log(resp.data)
              setData(resp.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
              setData(false)
            });
    
    
        };
    
        fetchAuthData()
      }, []);
    
      console.log(data)
      // Logic to check if backEndResponse is true or false
      if (data === true) {
        const authorized = { loggedIn: true }
        return authorized && authorized.loggedIn;
      } else {
        const authorized = { loggedIn: false }
        return authorized && authorized.loggedIn;
      }
    
    };
    
    
    const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
      const isAuth = useAuth();
      return isAuth ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Is `fetchAuthData` not making the GET request and updating the `data` state? Or are you trying to say that your `ProtectedRoutes` layout component needs to wait until the GET request has been processed and the state updated? Why isn't `useAuth` just returning `data`, it's already a boolean value?

Comment: It is making the GET request and when I console.log(resp.data) in the .then() section of my code it will show the correct boolean value but when I console.log(data) right above my if statement it will always show false. So it is like when I make the GET request it is not updating the value of data.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from what I can understand of your question, the issue is that the `ProtectedRoutes` layout component is using the initial `data` state, which is `false`, and handling the auth redirect ***before*** the actual auth GET request is fully processed.

You should use a third "indeterminant" state to hold off on rendering the `Outlet` or redirect until the auth status is confirmed.

Example:

```
const useAuth = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(); // <-- initially undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAuthData = async () => {
      await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/auth')
        .then(resp => {
          setData(!!resp.data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          setData(false)
        });
    };

    fetchAuthData()
  }, []);

  return data;
};
```

...

```
const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const isAuth = useAuth();

  if (isAuth === undefined) return null; // or loading indicator, etc...

  return isAuth ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
}
```